# Append to dynamically created element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I got a simple ajax call, that loads html into a fancybox modal:

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/basket/dealdeliverybox",
            success : 
               function(data) {
                    if(data != 'SKIP')
                    {
                        $('#dealSuggestBox').html(data);

                        $.fancybox($('#dealSuggestBox').html());
                    }
               },
            async:false
       });
```

Now I also got a zipcode keyup event, for the zipcode field inside this modal box:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#takeaway_delivery_zipcode', function(){
var zipcode = $(this).val();

if(zipcode.length == 4)
{
    $.post("basket/deliverycheck", { zipcode: zipcode },
       function(data) {
            $('#takeaway_status').removeClass('alert-danger').removeClass('alert-success');
            $('#takeaway_status').html(data.msg);
            $('#takeaway_status').addClass(data.css);
       }, 'json');
}
});
```

So whenever the user types in the 4 digits it runs a deliverycheck and it should respond the status to #takeaway_status.

Problem is now that it is not adding any html or remove/adding any classes to #takeaway_status.

I found out this is because that it is because it is inside this box content, which are loaded after the first ajax.

How can I append data to the dynamically created element with jQuery? How can i make jQuery listen to the new html too and not only the original page load content

Comment: In two words use event delegation. Full answer : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Does not help me much sir? I am already using event delegation as you can see